# Read pdf files using php

Tags: php, pdf, filereader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Hi,

I have a bulk of pdf documents. I want to read that using php script. I searched a lot, but everyone is about creating pdf files. Here I dont want to create pdf file but I want to read it. Is there any way to read it php?

-Arun

Comment: Define "read" - do you want to extract the text contents? What  about images?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 0):

You can easily read the contents of a PDF file using a command-line utility like Pdftotext which you can call through exec.

This is an example of what i mean, actually using [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

```
system("pdftotext your.pdf /tmp/txtfile.txt");
$text = file_get_contents("/tmp/txtfile.txt");
```

**EDIT**

didn't know about the dash syntax - this is even better:

```
$content = shell_exec('pdftotext your.pdf -');
```

This does require pdftotext to be installed on your server though. On a CentOS server this would be:

```
yum install xpdf
```

Comment: Thanks seengee for your fast reply. But can u make it more clear? call through exec means? I cant call it using a php file? P

Comment: @user please make clear first what you need.

Comment: how to install pdftotext? where to get it?

Comment: I have downloaded pdftotext. And now confused where to install it. Am using wamp server in a windows machine.

Comment: Done, Its working. I copied pdftotext in my system and gave full path to pdftotext.exe and it worked fine. Thanks to all replied to this thread, especially seengee.

Comment: ok, mark my answer as correct then please :)

Comment: How to run this in linux server? I tried it in my wamp. But my server is linux.

Comment: if you have it installed try `$content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext your.pdf -');`

Comment: I havent installed it. Also I cant find the /usr/local/bin path.

Comment: have you tried installing it? what Linux OS are you on?

Comment: Please find the server info I got from phpinfo.

Linux p3slh188.shr.phx3.secureserver.net 2.4.21-63.ELsmp #1 SMP Tue Nov 3 18:23:59 EST 2009 i686

Answer (score 0):

To just get the text from a PDF file, try these:
 - http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php
 - http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php (more in-depth)

For a more heavyweight solutions, have a look at:
 - http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/