# How to get a PDF file contents with PHP using FPDF/FPDI

Tags: php, pdf

i have pdf files that i need to get their text contents with php FPDF/FPDI.

thank you.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824010/open-pdf-file-in-fpdf-and-return-ist-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with FPDF/FPDI.

You may try [PDF Parser](http://pdfparser.org/) (if you can go with the GPL) or the [SetaPDF-Extracter](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/details/) (not free!) component. There are also some classes on google around but I don't want to suggest them, because their features are very limited.

Answer (score 1):

below is some available library which you can use in Javascript and can send that textarea into php

below is the gthub project 
https://github.com/hubgit/hubgit.github.com/tree/master/2011/11/pdftotext

below is the example
http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/