# Reading PDF files in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Can you read PDF files by using PHP code?

Comment: What do you want to do with the PDF? Are you trying to read textual data from it, or just combine several PDFs?

Comment: Please use the Search function before asking. This has been answered numerous times before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+pdf+files+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Either install a [command line script that can convert PDFs to text](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html) and execute this in PHP

```
$content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -'); //dash at the end to output content
```

([source](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php))

... or write [a PHP function like this](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php).

Comment: for using(shell_exec) the code above u gave, is there any supporting file is needed or this single code convert pdf to text files..

Comment: You need to install the command line script that I referred to in my first link.

Comment: oh k thank u very much its working fine... is there any other way or code to read php files..

Comment: If it's working, accept or upvote the answer so that the question is closed. What do you mean by "other code to read php files"?

Answer (score 3):

To read PDF files, you will need to install the XPDF ( http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html ) package, which includes "pdftotext." Once you have XPDF/pdftotext installed, you run the following PHP statement to get the PDF text:

```
$content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -'); //dash at the end to output content
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of my answer :p

Comment: slhck: sorry see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177726/is-there-any-library-available-in-php-to-convert-pdf-file-to-html/5177817#5177817

Comment: Oh I see.. was to be expected that this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a extension like

http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/

or

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html

Comment: actually i'm trying to form a tag cloud, so in tag cloud i tried by text files it working fine but when i was tried with pdf it's not working properly...