# Renaming a 900kb pdf file takes long time

Tags: php, performance, file-rename

I am trying to `rename()` a 900 KiB PDF file in PHP. It is taking a long time to rename it for some reason. I thought it should be instant.

This is on a CentOS server. While the file is being renamed I can get properties and it seems like `rename()` is copying and replacing the old file with new renamed file.

The old name and new name paths are in the same directory.

Has anyone stumbled upon this issue before?

---

### Code:

```
    //If exists change name and then return path
    $pieces = explode("@", $filename);
    $newName = $pieces[0].' '.$pieces[2];

    rename($uidPath.$filename, $uidPath.$newName);

    if (preg_match('/pdf/', $pieces[2]))
    {
        $result['status'] = '1';
        $result['path'] = 'path to file';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $result['status'] = '1';
        $result['path'] = 'path to file';
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that another process has the file locked and rename is waiting for the lock to release?  Renaming a file shouldn't result in it being copied at all and should be instant as you expect.

Comment: maybe you should show your code?

Comment: Is the process of renaming a file causing it to move from one disk partition to another?

Comment: show your code, otherwise we don't know how you rename that file. Not that it is more obvious then what the problem is, but it might be.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=934

Comment: @MikeBrant This is clearly written in the question: "The old name and new name paths are in the same directory."

Comment: I have just added the code, Sorry for earlier. I thought it's just a simple one liner and I should get away with it :)

Comment: does `$uidPath` end with a slash ??

Comment: The file name actually contains an '@' character?

Comment: I've seen this for NFS mounted file systems. Is this file local?

Comment: Perhaps using exec() with a call to 'mv filename newName' would work better?

Comment: @Baba, yes the uid path has slash at the end

Comment: @Wiseguy, The old name contains @ char in it

Comment: @BrentBaisley, I don't have clue of the file system but I could get back to you by asking our network admin

Comment: visit:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php
  and
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180718/reading-pdf-files-in-php

Comment: @pbvamsi I do not understand what those questions have to do with this question?

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine?

Comment: Suhosin pack active or is modified?

Comment: If you have just closed resource pointing to that file PHP will be quite slow to release the lock. I haven't found a way around it, so I just have it sleep for a second after close.

Comment: Did you actually profile it and found that `rename` is the bottleneck? also check the values of `$uidPath.$filename` and `$uidPath.$newName` in run-time using `var_dump` or a debugger.

Comment: @c2h5oh, Your point sounds interesting, as I do have file_put_content method called just before I am renaming that file. Does file_put_content creates file first and then write data incrementally? Or spits out entire file and content altogeather?

Comment: @Owl From PHP docs: `This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.` So most likely your rename is slowed down by the very same issue I had - `fclose` being slow to release the file lock.

Comment: @c2h5oh, hmmm...thats a good catch! Let me re-work the logic so the file only gets renamed after entire file is wriiten succesfully.

Comment: How many files do you have in this folder?

Comment: @c2h5oh, Hey mate! could you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. It was indeed the locking issue.

Comment: @Owl Done :-) BTW did you find a way around it?

Comment: Nah I end up re-engineering the process :) now I am changing name twice. First time with temp keyword in it and then the name of file by which I am checking, if file exists. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is for some reason very slow to release file lock on `fclose()`, so if you are writing to the file prior to moving it you might have to wait for a bit. I've had this very problem with a low priority background job, so I didn't really look into why this happens or what I can do to prevent it - I just added 1 second sleep between `fclose()` and `rename`.