# Unable to read PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

I want to read pdf file in php and store the content in the variable without installing anything.

I am able to read doc file and .txt file but i am getting some special characters when i read pdf file.

Comment: simply write "read pdf using php" in google.You can find first 3 links of SO by which you can eaisly read the pdf.Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as well because you get know that which and How can you ask questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) as well as [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) for this purpose
Here is the sample code of FPDI which you can find on their website as well as further support

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('TestDoc.pdf');
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D');>
//further user code
```

You can also get some help from [this blog](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about useful information in reading PDF in PHP in following Links -

**1:** http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

**2:** [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Hope this will help you.