# Determine if PDF file has searchable text in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, ocr

We have hundreds of PDF files on a server. Some of them contain searchable text and others do not.

I was asked to find out which are searchable and which are not.

Does anybody know of a way to read in a bunch of PDFs and determine if that PDF document contains text that is searchable/selectable or if the pdf only contains non-selectable/searchable text which needs to be OCRd?

**I don't even need to actually read in the text; I just need to be able to detect possibly by tags or keywords, something that suggests that there are fonts or something like that in the raw data.**

Are there tags in a searchable PDF that make it easy to detect?

Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few libraries to create PDFs but reading them in PHP, not that many. I'd say using a third-party program (maybe pdftotext?) to extract text would be your best option.

Comment: That's a good question :-) I would try to look for some text, like for example searching for a space or so, but this question would definitely deserve a longer thinking

Comment: I don't think PHP is the right tool for this task.

Comment: PHP can read in a raw pdf file so surely there is a way to detect text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [modify this code(pdf2text)](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php) to suit your purposes, I believe.  Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582794/1572077) might get you to the right spot as well.