# How to Import data from already make PDF Forms in php?

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF form and i want to import this PDF Form in PHP and then populate all fields from database then create new PDF.
is that possible?

If yes then please guide me how can i inert data in already make PDF forms.

Here is the PDF form file which i want to Import. 
[Download PDF](http://zzlearn.laptoppricesinpakistan.com.pk/Appearance_Testing%20Test854729.pdf)

Comment: your question has two parts, one is converting pdf contents to php. you can [check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php) out. as for inserting in database, there are plenty, you can just google

Answer (score 0):

If you do take into account your working time etc. you might actually consider commercial server-side form filling tool, such as FDFMerge by Appligent (for simple filling, the Lite version would be sufficient). In this case, you won't need to noodle around the PDF, trying to interpret it, and attempting to write something back.

In this scenario, you would export an FDF from the database, which is rather easy to accomplish, as FDF is a simple text file. How it has to look can be found with ease as well, by taking the form, filling it out, and exporting the data as FDF. And then, the rest is "filling out the blanks".

For using libraries to do server-side filling, links have already been provided. Just a note: make sure that you will get a good and functional PDF, by relying on well-reputated libraries.