# Can any one help me in reading PDF file to other format?

Tags: pdf, csv

Can any one help me in reading PDF file to other format?
I am trying to read PDF file into csv in php.But there is no option I am getting in PHOP.Can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into this: http://www.pdfparser.org/

Or maybe in this post: [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)