# How to read a text from pdf using Php..?

Tags: php

**How to read a text from pdf with PHP**

-- Actually i am trying to make a converter in which i read a text from pdf and convert it into a word document. If anyone has developed this plugin, then positively help me out in this task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please search before posting a new question. There are already many questions about this subject, like the duplicate linked by @Mr.Smith.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here by @Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582794/550992)

Check out FPDF (with FPDI):

http://www.fpdf.org/

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

These will let you open an pdf and add content to it in PHP. I'm guessing you can also use their functionality to search through the existing content for the values you need.

Another possible library is TCPDF: http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf