# Fetch Information from editable PDF form using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

Using PHP how can I show editable PDF form and then on submit get the information? I have a PDF form which I have converted to editable PDF form using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro, I now want to show it in the browser so that user can fill. On submit I want to get the information entered in that form and store in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To read and write a pdf you can use some PDF libraries like [FPDI](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/)  or [PDFtoHTML](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/).

Follow this link [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

But in your use case I am not sure why you are using a PDF form if your intention is just to save the user inputs into database. I would recommend use a HTML form instead, will be easier for you to manage.

Comment: Yes, you are right in saying that I should use web HTML forms. But actually those forms are for young students and are very beautifully desinged by the client, so I just want to use that to save myself lot of time for designing layout and images and everything.