# Get content of PDF file in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

I have a FlipBook jquery page and too many ebooks(pdf format) to display on it. I need to keep these PDF's hidden so that I would like to get its content with PHP and display it with my FlipBook jquery page. (instead of giving whole pdf I would like to give it as parts).

Is there any way i can get whole content of PDF file with PHP?
I need to seperate them according to their pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read pdf files with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Comment: What do you mean by "get whole content of a PDF file"?

Comment: @Webeng I mean images and texts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use PDF Parser (PHP PDF Library) to extract each
and everything from PDF's.

**PDF Parser Library Link**: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

**Online Demo Link:** https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/master/doc/Usage.md

**Documentation Link:** https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/tree/master/doc

Sample Code:

```
<?php
 
// Include Composer autoloader if not already done.
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
 
// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');
 
$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
 
?>
```

Regarding another part of your Question:

**How To Convert Your PDF Pages Into Images:**

You need [`ImageMagick`](https://www.php.net/imagick) and [`GhostScript`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/)

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
?>
```

The `[0]` means `page 1`.

Comment: PDF Parser for only getting text. I also need to get images in PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but rendering PDF to images is not very effective solution. It have to be readable on mobile and images looks bad on mobile.

Comment: @BerkKaya : Seems like then may be you will need to target specific parts of the pages to just take the images but I don't think so if that is possible dynamically..! If it solved your question so please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai : how to regenerate pdf after parsing in the same format. i am able to parse but stuck how to regenerate?

Comment: @KaushaThakkar : Regenerating PDF back from simple text won't be possible as during parsing the wysiwug pdf version turns into simple text...Only it would be possible if you try to parse the PDF into Markup text and then you can reconstruct your PDF using the same Markup text..!

Comment: @KaushaThakkar : Instead you would need to turn your PDF into something which can hold it's true form like DOCX etc and then you can reconstruct the PDF from your docx...Take a look at : http://www.zamzar.com/

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai : Thanks for your input. pdftk is exactly doing what i want. but in my case, the form field value is not what i want to replaced?

Comment: @KaushaThakkar : Do you mean this one?? https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai : Yes but that only converts the form field values. and in my case they are not form fields :(

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai : i am able to parse the data and modify by using the `$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();` this but i also want to convert it back to pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135590/discussion-between-kausha-thakkar-and-umair-shah-yousafzai).

Comment: FYI this PDFparser is quite buggy and has masses of open issues, even in 2020, so always run proper manual tests to make sure you get the expected result!

Comment: This library doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @Simon30 Updated the links. The library official website is not there anymore while the library do still exist on github and composer etc.

Comment: I managed to do my task using a java library finally but thanks for the update !