# Read text from rectangular area of a PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, box

I want to read text from given pdf file. I want option, so I can extract text from given box. Somewhere my text is in English and somewhere it is in Hindi.

I am trying to use 
How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].