# Reading PDF file with PHPWord library

Tags: php, phpword

I have tried reading the .docx file. I am successful in reading the .docx file. But I have to read .pdf file with PHPWord.

Any idea How can I do it?

I have tried the code

```
// Read contents
$source = "./example.pdf";
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source, 'Word2007');

$data = '';
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText($data);

$name = "officefile";
$source = __DIR__ . "/results/{$name}.html";

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save($source);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPWord cannot read PDF files. Please see [this Github issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1010) too see that it is out of scope of the project.

Some alternative methods of reading PDF files with PHP can be found in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php).